# On package multicol, on build it shows that package multicol.idx is not found. miktek console could not find the packge to install

Tags: multicol

[image]
I am using multicol package to prepare column writing, but on build, it shows that package multicol.idx is not found. I tried to instal the multicol package from miktek console and the package could not found online repositories associated with miktek console.

Comment: It is advisable to shorten the title, and post the text (not the image) in the question.

Comment: Why are you running `bibtex`? Shouldn't it be `pdflatex` or something similar?

Comment: Don't use texify. And better don't use file names with spaces, makeindex gets confused by your file name.